# The Leaftlet `Multiverse` issue

Tags: leaflet

I hope someone can lend some insight here. My customer is complaining about what he calls the "multiverse" issue in Leaflet.

I apologize if I'm not using the right words to describe the problem.

As everyone knows, in leaflet you can scroll right/left on the map giving the appearance that you are "scrolling around the world"...however, each world map to the left and right are actually independently mapped using a continuum of longitudes...

For example, this picture shows (roughly) three earths:
[image: multiverse]

The left one from -540 to -180, middle from -180 to 180, right from 180 to 540.

And note the pin on the middle earth doesn't show on the left or right earths.

Is there any reasonable way to eliminate the "multiverse" feature (shy of replicating all of the elements N number of times)?

Comment: You can use tile layer `noWrap: true` option.

Comment: I was still hoping to be able to pan left and right, so this isn't quite it. Thanks for commenting

Comment: If you have only markers, you could use https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.RepeatedMarkers

Comment: unfortunately I've got lines and polygons also...the worldCopyJump answer below resolved my issue sufficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options mentioned in the [options for the `Map` object](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-factory).

- Set `maxBounds` with a longitude range of -180, 180

  - `maxBoundsViscosity` can be used to control the behaviour of panning at the edges
- Set `worldCopyJump` to `True`

Comment: the bounds don't really help, because my customer has a scenario that may cover the pacific ocean, so cutting it off. in the middle doesn't resolve the issue.

Looking at `worldCopyJump`, but it seems to have the same sort of issue.

Comment: Anything in the Pacific unfortunately comes up against [tag:antimeridian] issues, and there is no good solution in Leaflet, shy of doing things with non-default coordinate reference systems and producing your own basemap tiles to match that projection. [tag:OpenLayers] tends to do some of this stuff better, but tends to be a slightly more difficult API.

Comment: I accepting worldCopyJump as the correct answer here. I needed to supplement by creating 2 additional markers, one at location-180 longitude and one at location+180 longitude. Thanks!